# Why I am getting a Server Error(500) in production?

Tags: reactjs, api, django-rest-framework, axios

I created an app with DjangoREST , React and Redux it is Deployed on Heroku , but I am getting a Server Error(500) . I used allauth for token Authentication . Every urls is working fine in development but not in production .

I am successfully getting a token by **/rest-auth/login/** url and the token is also passed successfully in the headers as **"Authorization" : Token *token*** .

This the error I am getting also I console.log the error -

[image]

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from todo import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/todos/', views.TodoList.as_view()),
    path('api/todos/<int:pk>/', views.TodoDetail.as_view()),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('rest-auth/registration/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('api/user/', views.UserAPI.as_view()),
    re_path(r'^', views.FrontendAppView.as_view())
]
```

**settings.py**

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'dj-react-todo.herokuapp.com']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',    
    'todo',
    'corsheaders' ,
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth' ,
    'allauth',
    'allauth.socialaccount' ,
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build', 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = (
        'content-type' ,
        'xsrfheadername' ,
        'xsrfcookiename', 
        'X-CSRFTOKEN'
)
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XCSRF-TOKEN"

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none" 
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
```

**views.py**

```
class TodoList(APIView):
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        todos = Todo.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        serializer = TodoSerializer(todos, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer =  TodoSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(user=request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Todo
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class TodoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Todo
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'title', 'description', 'completed', 'deadline', 'crucial')

    def create(self , validated_data):
        return Todo.objects.create(**validated_data)


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')
```

This is how I created my actionCreator to get all the todos created by a user -

```
import axios from 'axios' ;
import { ADD_TODO, FETCH_TODOS, DELETE_TODO, TOGGLE_CHECKBOX, CRUCIAL_TODO} from './types' ;
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "XCSRF-TOKEN";
axios.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'PATCH, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS';

export const getTodos = () => dispatch => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    const config = {
        'headers': {
            'Authorization': `Token ${token}` ,
        }
    }

    if (token){
        axios.get('https://dj-react-todo.herokuapp.com/api/todos/', config)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_TODOS ,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error , I already pass the token and I am getting the authenticated user also through that token .
I checked the heroku logs and it is also showing 500 Server Error .

Comment: Not really related but you're asking for username 2 times in `/register`.

Comment: Can you recreate the error with DEBUG=True so we can see the traceback? Or maybe find it if its logged somewhere?